# Why reading a function result to variable with v="$()" doesn't work in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I would like to print the factorial of number read from `stdin` but I cannot do it this way (this prints empty line):

```
#!/bin/bash

factorial()
{
  if [ $1 -le 1 ]
  then
    return 1
  else
    factorial $[$1-1]
    return $[$1*$?]
  fi
}

read num

ret="$(factorial $num)"
echo "${ret}"
```

This way worked but I feel it's a bit worse (as I cannot save the variable for later):

```
factorial $num
echo $?
```

Why is the first method not working? ([link to highly upvoted answer on SO that explains it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4651495/675100))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method works if you `echo` the result in the factorial function rather than trying to return it.

The `$(...)` syntax evaluates to the output of the command you run. Since your code, as it is, has no output, `ret` will be empty.

```
#!/bin/bash

factorial()
{
  if [ $1 -le 1 ]
  then
    echo 1
  else
    part=$(factorial $(($1-1)))
    echo $(($1*$part))
  fi
}

read num

ret="$(factorial $num)"
echo "${ret}"
```